# Solr Integration : HTTP ERROR: 404 when integrating with solr

Tags: .net, apache, tomcat, solr, solrnet

I have been trying to **setup Solr with Apache Tomcat**, and I can see the localhost:8080 Tomcat page, but when I try to reach the localhost:8080/solr page I get the following message:

**"HTTP Status 404 - /solr**

**type Status report**

**message /solr**

**description The requested resource is not available.**

**Apache Tomcat/9.0."**

Can anyone help me to configure Solr With .net properly so that I can proceed with Full Text Search with Solr.

Comment: What does the Tomcat log show? Tomcat isn't a officially supported container for Solr any longer, so you might have issues in the future as well. Solr is now self-contained with a bundled Jetty installation.

Comment: Which Solr version are you trying to run in Tomcat?